# What does "gather out the stones" mean?

Tags: isaiah, prophecy

Isa 62:10

> Go through, go through the gates; prepare ye the way of the people; cast up, cast up the highway; gather out the stones; lift up a standard for the people.

What does "gather out the stones" mean?

Comment: This relates to the parable of the sower. Gathering out the stones is essential, or the crop will sprout up, having no depth of earth, and there will be no fruit. Here, in terms of progress on a highway, removing stumbling-blocks is as essential as removing stones from cultivate land. This is the bare meaning of the text. If you seek further, then an edit is necessary.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks Nigel, I agree with your comment. : )

Answer (score 1):

The phrase in the MT is  סַקְּל֣וּ מֵאֶ֔בֶן

The verb is the piel imperative 2nd person masculine plural of סקל.  It means to throw stones, but in this context "clear stones," that is throw out of the way.

Figure 1. Senses of סקל as used in the MT (generated with Logos Bible Software).
[image]

מֵאֶ֔בֶן is the singular noun for stone (אֶבֶן, eben) with the prefixed preposition מִן. The most common meaning is *from*.  Here it is the second more common meaning  *of*, "clear of stones."  You could translate "clear out or throw out the stones."

Figure 2. Translations of מִן in the ESV (generated with Logos Bible Software).
[image]

Comment: Thanks Perry, the KJV translation doesn't do to well in this case, as 'Gather' and 'Throw out' are almost opposite in terms of meaning, definitely changes the meaning of that sentence.

Comment: From the practicality of clearing stones, which they did at the time of the KJV ad well as Isaiah's time, stones would end up bunched on the side of the road.  Here they are not clearing fields.  But, if they were clearing fields, they would build walls with the stones; what they would also do if the road were next to someone's field.  They would add the stones to the wall.  Probably for the people at the time of the KJV, gathering stones had the same meaning as clearing stones and the way they would express such.